# bq query with a destination table vrs insert statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data in a `BigQuery table(src_table)` and I want to insert the data into another `BigQuery table(tgt_table)`.

I have two options of inserting the data

`Run a bq query --destination_table=tgt_table "select req_columns from src_table"`

or

`insert into tgt_table(req_cloumn_list) select req_columns from src_table`.

Which of the two methods are recommended? Is there any difference between the two methods in terms of performance and best practices.

For the first statement where I use a destination table, I have the option to overwrite, append or write only when empty options. Can I use similar options with the DML also?

The actual inserts I am trying to process is a complex query involving a nested table and multiple joins. The data processed may be more than 1TB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options should not have noticeable performance differences. One difference is that when you use INSERT, the statistics for the job will have [ddlOperationPerformed and ddlTargetTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobStatistics#JobStatistics2) properties set. Yes, the functionality is different in general between DML statements and the "write disposition" option for SELECT statements, but if you can, it's best to use DML statements since the experience will be similar to other SQL dialects.